# How to select and deselect the thumbnail images in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to i phone programming.How to select and deselect the thumbnail images.Right now what i did i have taken custom button using that i am adding custom image to thumbnails,it is mainly used for i can know that these thumbnail images are selected.like that,if select any thumbnail image means,custom button is attaching to each every selected thumbnail image.
Now what i want means if i again click on same image means i want remove custom button image form the selected thumbnail.again if i selected means it have attach that custom button image and if again select on same image means i have remove that custom button image form the thumbnail.Can any body tell what logic i have use here.
Here is my code

```
- (void)handleThumbClick:(id)sender
{


        NSLog(@"yes selected");

        FGalleryPhotoView *photoView = (FGalleryPhotoView*)[(UIButton*)sender superview];

        customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"1" 
                                          withStringColor:[UIColor greenColor] 
                                           withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor] 
                                           withBadgeFrame:YES 
                                      withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor grayColor] 
                                                withScale:1.0
                                              withShining:YES];     


        b =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        b.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100,100);
        [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [b setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       // [b setTag:4];

        NSLog(@"Thumb click Fgallerview controller");

        [photoView addSubview:b];
        [photoView addSubview:customBadge1];

}
```

The above code for if click on any thumbnail means its attaching the custom button image to that thumbnail image.Now what i want means if again if click on same thumbnail i have remove that custom thumbnail image.
For example in thumbnail view i have 10 images is displaying now i want to select only 5 images if click on any 5 thumbnail means its attaching custom button image to 5 selected images.Now what i want means if want in selected 5 thumbnail images having custom button image.now if i select any selected image means i have to uncheck that selected image ,means i want to remove that  custom button image form the selected thumbnail.
Can any body tell me  how to do this

And one more thing i now that by using ELCimagepickercontroller we can able to select multiple images,but that only gallery images but here i am displaying from private document directory folder images..Please help meee
Thanks
Aslam

Comment: set thumbnil image to setBackgroung and selection image to setImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set thumbnail image as `setBackgroundImage` and set initial tag=0;

```
-(IBAction)handleThumbClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    if (btn.tag==0)
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag=1;
    }
    else{
        [btn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag=0;
    }

}
```